# Tang inscription translation (Characters identified: 大唐年製)

Tags: translation

Can anyone assist with translation of the characters as shown. They are incised into the underside of a Tang sancai figure of a resting camel[image]

Answer (score 2):

大唐年製 (Made in the era of the Tang Dynasty)

Comment: drooze a clarification, would the inscription character formating or other characteristics suggest a modern inscription  19/20 th C

Comment: @MauriceTurner I'm sorry, I'm not an expert in detecting whether an item is authentic or not. You also shouldn't expect this community to know anything about that (this is a Chinese Language community rather than a item collecting community).

Comment: drooze - thanks for your comments and please accept my apologies for not correctly understanding the intent of your community.

Comment: @MauriceTurner I'm not an expert either, but think red flags should be raised about authenticity. In particular, I think incisions of this type would also specify the era name (年號) and not just the dynasty name. For example, they should have been 大唐贞觀年製，大明洪武年製 etc. instead of just 大唐(明)年製.